# Can I execute a ahk command directly, outside of a script?

Tags: autohotkey

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\v2\AutoHotkey64.exe" /command SendInput !{F4}
```

/force /restart /ErrorStdOut /Debug /CPn /Validate /iLib "OutFile" /include "IncFile" /script

These are the options listed in the official documentation

Are there any more options parameters that runs a command directly?

Or are there any more ways to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a list of the supported options. If it's not there, there isn't one.

Comment: Well, there are some useful library like VD.ahk that made moving windows between desktop on automate very easy. Would be good to have those commands directly available in a cmd or pwsh

Comment: @KenWhite that's extremely incorrect. Yes, AHK is convenient for hotkeys, but it's far more capable than that. There are endless hotkeyless use cases.